# using date of datetime in group by and order by in single SELECT versus using subquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I (suddenly?) have trouble getting this very simple query to work on Google BigQuery without using a subquery and not sure why.

The data contains a datetime column and I just want to check up on the number of rows per day.
However, it keeps complaining I'm using the datetime column 'which is neither grouped or aggregated'.

```
SELECT date(datetime_col) as row_date, count(*) as count
FROM table1
GROUP BY date(datetime_col)
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Without the ORDER BY it works just fine. When I add the ORDER BY it suddenly complains the

> 'SELECT list expression references column 'datetime_col' which is
> neither grouped nor aggregated'

If I remove the count and group by and order by on the date then it does work.

Now if I use a subquery to do the date casting in there it does work:

```
SELECT row_date, count(row_date) as count FROM 
(SELECT date(datetime_col) as row_date FROM table1)
GROUP BY row_date
ORDER BY count DESC
```

So I'm wondering what is going on why the first single select query is not working and if that can be fixed without using the subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `row_date` into `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT date(datetime_col) as row_date, count(*) as count
FROM table1
GROUP BY row_date
ORDER BY count DESC
```